# Automatically generate values for #define using vi[m]

Tags: c++, c, vim, macros, vi

As of now, I have the following in a `.h` file which has the following:

```
#define ONE 
#define TWO
#define THREE
#define FOUR
..
.
#define FIFTY
```

Using `vi[m]`, how can we generate the replacement text for the macros which should be as follows:

```
#define ONE 1
#define TWO 2
#define THREE 3
#define FOUR 4
..
.
#define FIFTY 50
```

Problem statement: Given lower-limit (1), upper-limit (50) and step (i.e. increment by 1 or 2 or 3, etc at a time) - what is the `vi` command to automatically generate values in the above mentioned macros?

UPDATE: I have no option of using `enum`.

Comment: No enum?! Stop using ancient <strike>DevC++</strike> oh <strike>Borland C++ 3.1</strike> sh\*t <strike>TinyCC</strike> wait... _`The original K&R dialect of the C programming language did not have enumerated types, but they were added in the ANSI standard for C, which became C89`_ - [You don't have an excuse, really.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumerated_type#C_and_syntactically_similar_languages)

Comment: Can you explain why you cannot use an `enum`? I doubt it is because the compiler doesn't support it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go ahead and put a "1" after the `#define ONE` (where it should be at the final state). Go to the beginning of that line (with the cursor over the #) and press the following keys (where C-a means "ctrl+a"):

> <kbd>q</kbd>
>   <kbd>q</kbd> `# record macro q`
>   
>   <kbd>3</kbd>
>   <kbd>w</kbd>
>   <kbd>h</kbd>
>   <kbd>y</kbd>
>   <kbd>$</kbd>
>   <kbd>j</kbd>
>   <kbd>$</kbd>
>   <kbd>p</kbd>
>   <kbd>C-a</kbd>
>   <kbd>^</kbd>
>   <kbd>q</kbd> `# end macro q`
>   
>   <kbd>4</kbd>
>   <kbd>8</kbd>
>   <kbd>@</kbd>
>   <kbd>q</kbd> `# repeat macro 48x`

Now the explanation:

- <kbd>q</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> = record a macro called "q"
- <kbd>3</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> = move three words to the right
- <kbd>h</kbd> = move one character left (over the space before the number)
- <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>$</kbd> = yank until the end of the line
- <kbd>j</kbd> = move down one line
- <kbd>$</kbd> = go to the end of the line
- <kbd>p</kbd> = paste
- <kbd>C-a</kbd> = increment the number under the cursor
- <kbd>^</kbd> = go to the beginning of the line
- <kbd>q</kbd> = stop recording macro
- <kbd>4</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>@</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> = run the macro 48 times

Let me know if you didn't understand, or if I understood it wrongly. It works correctly in my PC. If you want to increment by more then one at a time, simply put that multiplier in front of C-a (e.g. 3C-a)

Comment: Man, I've really got to stop using `nano` and bite the bullet and start using something more powerful!

Answer (score 2):

Line-select (`C-V`) all the lines and type

```
:r !awk '{print $0, NR}'
```

Comment: or just `:!nl` and then `:norm dw$p` on that selection. `@:` if necessary to repeat that last step. See http://downloads.sehe.nl/stackoverflow/14640713.mpg

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I assume that all those `#define` lines are continued, that is, there is no empty lines or other lines in between, e.g. this case doesn't exist:

```
#define foo

#define bar
whatever
#define another
```

*** I added a solution for this case at the end of this answer ***

---

Then there could be two different situations, first one is simpler, the `#define block` sits at the beginning of your file. which means 1st `#define` on 1st line.

in this case you could just do

```
:%s/^#define.*/\=submatch(0)."  ".line(".")/g
```

which will simply add line number at the end of each `#define` statement.

The other situation is, your `#define statement block` sits in the middle somewhere of the file.

**This solution is more generic, also works for the first scenario.**

You could add a mapping

```
:nnoremap <leader>do :let x=line(".")<cr>:%s/^#define.*/\=submatch(0)." ".(line(".")-x+1)/g<cr>
```

then move your cursor to the 1st `#define` statement, press `<leader>do`, it will do the work for you. In this way, you don't have to manually insert "1", don't have to record macro either.

it works like:
[image]

**external cmd in vim (awk)**

awk is nuclear weapon of text processing, using awk in this case also a nice way to go. it could handle those separated #define statements for example:
your file looks like:

```
/*
   comments
*/
#define ONE 

//comment
#define TWO



//empty lines
#define THREE

#define FOUR
```

if you in vim type :

```
:%!awk '/^\#define/{$0= $0" "++x}1'
```

your file turns into:

```
/*
   comments
*/
#define ONE  1

//comment
#define TWO 2



//empty lines
#define THREE 3

#define FOUR 4
```

Comment: +1 for explaining various cases and solution for them! Excellent. Thanks!